# Multiclass vs. multilabel fitting

Tags: scikit-learn

In scikit-learn tutorials, I found the following paragraphs in the section 'Multiclass vs. multilabel fitting'.
I couldn't understand why the following codes generate the given results.

**First**

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

X = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [4, 5], [3, 2], [3, 1]]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]

classif = OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=SVC(random_state=0))
classif.fit(X, y).predict(X)


array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2])



y = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
classif.fit(X, y).predict(X)


array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

**Next**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
y = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [2, 4]]
y = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
classif.fit(X, y).predict(X)


array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: What exactly is it you don't understand--what results are you expecting?

Comment: I didn't know why the predicted values are different from the binarized y for the above two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Label binarization in `scikit-learn` will transform your targets and represent them in a label indicator matrix. This label indicator matrix has the shape `(n_samples, n_classes)` and is composed as follows:

- each row represents a sample
- each column represents a class
- each element is 1 if the sample is labeled with the class and 0 if not

In your **first** example, you have a target collection with 5 samples and 3 classes. That's why transforming `y` with `LabelBinarizer` results in a 5x3 matrix. In your case, `[1, 0, 0]` corresponds to class `0`, `[0, 1, 0]` corresponds to class `1` and so forth. Notice that in each row there is only one element set to 1, since each sample can have one label only.

In your **next** example, you have a target collection with 5 samples and 5 classes. That's why transforming `y` with `MultiLabelBinarizer` results in a 5x5 matrix. In your case, `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]` corresponds to the multilabel `[0, 1]`, `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` corresponds to the multilabel `[1, 3]` and so forth. The key difference to the first example is that each row can have multiple elements set to 1, because each sample can have multiple labels/classes.

The predicted values you get follow the very same pattern. They are however not equivalent to the original values in `y` since your classification model has obviously predicted different values. You can check this with the `inverse_transform()` of the binarizers:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer


mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

y = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [2, 4]])
y_bin = mlb.fit_transform(y)

# direct transformation
[[1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]]


# prediction of your classifier
y_pred = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

# inverting the binarized values to the original classes
y_inv = mlb.inverse_transform(y_pred)

# output
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (0, 2), (0, 2)]
```

Comment: Do you mean that the differences between the binarized y and the predicted values came from the classification error? Does this error come from the binarization? If we predict the same data with the plain classification model without binarization, can we get the same predicted results with the original y?

Comment: Yes, the difference in the predicted values comes from the classifier. And you can test if you get better results without binarization. But I highly doubt it. Having 5 samples for a multilabel classification problem like this is just not enough to fit a model for perfect predictions. You will most certainly need more data.

Comment: @issong if your question is answered, please accept my answer and consider upvoting. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)